# How to run 2 lines in GUI command line shortcut

Tags: debian, command, gui, application, desktop-shortcuts

I've installed a new version of an app.

Currently it's GUI shortcut leads to `/usr/bin/flameshot`

[image: /usr/bin/flameshot]

But I've installed it in a different path and now I run it from the terminal like this:

`cd ~/Applications/Flameshot; ./Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage`

How can I replace the GUI shortcut to run the new version without blocking the terminal (background)

Comment: Can't you go to Browse and navigate to the one that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `cd` at all. Just use the full path:

```
/home/YOUR_USERNAME/Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage
```

For example, if your username is `elad`, then you would put:

```
/home/elad/Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage
```

If you are unsure what the full path is, you can check by opening a terminal and running:

```
readlink -f ~/Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage
```

Then you can put whatever that returns in the GUI.

Comment: how do i change the path of `/usr/bin/flameshot` to `readlink -f ~/Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage
`

Comment: @EladBenda you don't. You currently use `/usr/bin/flameshot` in your launcher, the thing you show in your screenshot. Just change that to _the output_ of the command `readlink -f ~/Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage`. That will simply show the full path to `~/Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage`, it should be something like `/home/elad//Applications/Flameshot/Flameshot-0.10.1.x86_64.AppImage` and that is what you should use.

Comment: How can I clean/trash the content of `/usr/bin/flameshot` jsut `rm` for this?